# Deleting A TableView Cell Populated By A Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

So, deleting a table view cell is pretty straight forward. You remove the object from the array, and reload the table views data. Now... I have a table view that is populated from an NSMutableDictionary rather than array (we need to because we are parsing data and storing it). Does anyone know how to delete a cell via this method? I've tried simply calling `[tableView reloadData];` which surprisingly worked, but obviously created an endless loop. I do not like endless loops. Does anyone have any suggestions? I couldn't find any relevant information in my research.

This is some relevant code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate:

```
        if (![frString isEqual:@"COOL STUFF"] && [subString isEqualToString:@"COOL"]) {
            NSLog(@"A COOL is showing where it shouldn't, and it's %@", subString);
            //remove all cells starting with COOL

            [myDictionary removeObjectForKey:[self.dictName objectAtIndex:row]];
            [tableView reloadData];

        }
```

**Also, I'd rather hide the cell instead of permanently removing the info from the dictionary. Is this possible?**

Comment: You should modify your data source *before* `reloadData` is done to refresh the view.  Once you get into `cellForRow...` it's too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you're doing wrong :

- You shouldn't remove the rows in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because that's called when the tableview wants to render. So you remove a row, and then it renders again, calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,...
- Either delete the rows, or reload the data. `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` deletes sets of rows with animation, `reloadData` reloads the whole tableView, so it cancels the animation, and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` becomes pointlesss
- Ensure that you return the proper `numberOfRowsInSection:` did you remove the data from your dictionary ?

Comment: Ah I understand... So I should call this in which delegate method?

Comment: What triggers the cell deletion ?

Comment: Nothing yet. It is not an editable table view. Do you know if there is a way to hide the cell rather than delete the info from my dictionary?

Comment: You should do it when the dictionary is loaded. Remove all the objects you don't want there.